# How to specify text location for a title page?

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to specify text within certain locations of a title page, such as title of essay a quarter down the page, my name half way down, etc. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, outlines,tensor,amssymb,amsmath,wasysym,ulem,cancel,textcomp,fancyhdr,xfrac,multicol,hyperref,setspace}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, left=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm,right=2.54cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
  Insert Witty Title Here: Witty Subtitle Here\\[3.81cm]

  Jane Doe\\[7.62cm]


  \doublespacing
  {A Class\\ 
  Dr. Some Body\\
  13 November 2012}\\[22.86cm]
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

As y'all can see, I have tried to specify the locations relative to a letter size page, but it's not rendering the way I would like it to, and neither does changing the size do anything.

Any advice, I would very much appreciate. Thanks!

Just as an aside: I don't know if anyone is looking at how many packages I have and thinking, "Wow, that's sure alot" or maybe not because it's reasonably normal... but yes I do use lots of packages.

Comment: The optional lengths in square brackets following a double slash as **not** absolute page positions, but rather the amount of vertical space to insert at that point.  You should use a `\par` to terminate a paragraph, and a `\vspace{<length>}` to insert the desired vertical space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I have defined `\QuarterPage` to be the vertical space of 1/4 of the page, and added `\vspace*{\QuarterPage}` before the title, after the title so that the name is half way on the page, and another after this so that other material starts around 3/4 of the page:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `showframe` option to the `geometry` package was used just to show the page margins.  This should be removed in actual usage.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, outlines,tensor,amssymb,amsmath,wasysym,ulem,cancel,textcomp,fancyhdr,xfrac,multicol,hyperref,setspace}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, left=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,showframe]{geometry}


\newlength{\QuarterPage}
\setlength{\QuarterPage}{2.25in}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\QuarterPage}
Insert Witty Title Here: Witty Subtitle Here
\par\vspace*{\QuarterPage}  Jane Doe
\par\vspace*{\QuarterPage}
{\doublespacing A Class

  Dr. Some Body

  13 November 2012}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```